# Google Cloud Printing from a specific tray

Tags: c#, google-cloud-print

I am trying to implement silent printing from a .Net web application using Google Cloud Printing, the requirement is to print different documents from different tray like the invoices from Tray 1, Envelops from Tray 2, Visiting Cards from Tray 3.

The following is the code that I am trying:

```
postString.Params.Add(new PostDataParam { Name = "vendor_ticket_item", Value = "{\"vendor_ticket_item\":[{\"id\":\"psk:JobInputBin\",\"value\":\"ns0000:Tray 2\"}]}", Type = PostDataParamType.Field });
p.Params.Add(new PostDataParam { Name = "title", Value = title, Type = PostDataParamType.Field });
```

This is not working, I have even tried to with different options at https://www.google.com/cloudprint/simulate.html -> Job Submit API and none seems to get documents printed from a specific tray.

Please suggest if anyone has achieved Google Cloud Printing from a specific tray from any kind of code

Comment: Have you managed to find a way to do that? I expect to bump into this in my current project and have not come across a solution on the interwebs.